# XML-XSLT-XPATH : How to convert multiple XML elements to a string, separated by semicolon

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have just demonstrated my question as an input and output format as below. 
I have an input as xml document which consist of following data

```
    <Users>
          <user>
             <name>Mark Curtain</name>
             <email>mark@gmail.com</email>
             <username>mark</username>
          </user>
          <user>
             <name>Zuke Gossip</name>
             <email>zuke@abc.com</email>
             <username>zuke</username>
          </user>
          <user>
            <name>Villan Kiosk</name>
            <email>kv@gmail.com</email>
            <username>kvk</username>
         </user>
  </Users>
```

I want to fetch username and Name in one string which should be separated by semicolon(;).

For Example: **UserNames :** "mark;zuke;kvk"

Similar way for name also **Names :** "Mark Curtain;Zuke Gossip;Villan Kiosk"

***Is there any Xpath function to implement the same  ?
Is there any way in XSL transformation to get above strings as output ?***

Comment: Show what have you tried?

Comment: Oh yes, this is possible using XSL transformation. You just have to iterate on each `Users/user/username` to get the first string and on `name` to get the second(concatenating `;` after every element except the last).

Comment: Yes you are correct @LingamurthyCS. 
But it will be grateful if it is done by XPath or other functions of XSLT or XPath.

Comment: @Pawel , I have implemented in same way what LingamurthyCS has answered. I am in searching  of smart way to do it.

Comment: @TechnoCracker would you mind posting your implementation.

Comment: In xslt 2.0 you can use the `@separator` attribute on `xsl:value-of` and then the implementation is just one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>UserNames: &quot;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Users/user/username" separator=";"/>
        <xsl:text>&quot;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Names: &quot;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Users/user/name" separator=";"/>
        <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you @Joel M. Lamsen
instead of iterating each element better to select directly using xpath.
the attribute "seperator" I was not aware of it as I am new in Xpath and XSLT.

Thank you all to take interest in my question.